# Firebase module breaks Aurelia

Tags: firebase, aurelia

Observing an arcane bug when attempting to use the Firebase NPM module in a new Aurelia app. The bug triggers when I add `firebase` to the `aurelia.json` configuration file. This is the output from `au run --watch`:

`>au run --watch
Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
Finished 'readProjectConfiguration'
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildTypeScript'...
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'buildTypeScript'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
Tracing app...
Tracing environment...
Tracing main...
Tracing jog/index...
Tracing resources/index...
Tracing resources/attributes/show-progress...
Tracing resources/elements/identity...
Tracing resources/elements/nav-bar...
Tracing app...
Tracing jog/index...
Tracing resources/elements/identity...
Tracing resources/elements/nav-bar...
Tracing text...
Tracing aurelia-bootstrapper...
Tracing aurelia-history-browser...
Tracing aurelia-loader-default...
Tracing aurelia-logging-console...
Tracing aurelia-templating-binding...
Tracing aurelia-templating-resources...
Tracing aurelia-templating-router...
Tracing aurelia-testing...
Tracing firebase...
{ uid: 10,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error:
   { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<proj>\src\app-node.js']
     errno: -4058,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '<proj>\\src\\app-node.js',
     moduleTree: [ 'firebase' ],
     fileName: '<proj>/node_modules/firebase/firebase-node.js' },
  duration: [ 7, 862992973 ],
  time: 1474058088994 }`

There are five errors altogether, all almost identical. I've truncated it to one for brevity. `<proj>` represents the path to my project. The non-file `src\app-node.js` varies depending on which modules I import in the code.

The file `firebase-node.js` has a `require('./app-node')` statement. Looks like Aurelia is trying to fetch this dependency from the `src` folder instead of `node_modules/firebase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the same error with packages having multiple modules. You need to configure the dependencies section in `aurelia.json` as described in [Aurelia CLI documentation [Section: Adding Client Libraries to Your Project - CommonJS Package]](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6).

**aurelia.json** - build.bundles.dependencies

```
... other deps

{
    "name": "firebase",
    "path": "../node_modules/firebase",
    "main": "firebase"
},

... other deps
```